# How to make front end app immune to angular version changes

Tags: angular

suppose if I have created the first version of my application with the Angular 2 and after some time new version of angular is coming into the market.so how to prevent my application so that my code never breaks.

Comment: I suppose nothing in this world is immune to change in this world

Comment: Just stick to the conventions, and only update to minor (security) updates...

Comment: Thats why Angular provide an Update Guide: [https://update.angular.io/](https://update.angular.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `^` in front of every version number in `package.json` so you have bare version numbers which guarantees that the downloaded version of every package will always be the same and your code will never break.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't just break when a new version of Angular comes around (especially with a conservative configuration in `package.json`) since this doesn't mean that apps built with any previous versions will stop working...

That said, one should always **aim to keep developments [up to date](https://angular.io/guide/updating)** with the latest stable version of dependencies.